# How do I count vowels?

Tags: ruby, string

I've seen the solution and it more or less matches

```
Write a method that takes a string and returns the number of vowels
 in the string. You may assume that all the letters are lower cased. You can treat "y" as a consonant.
Difficulty: easy.

def count_vowels(string)
    vowel = 0
    i = 0
    while i < string.length  
        if (string[i]=="a" || string[i]=="e" || string[i]=="i" || string[i]=="o"|| string[i]=="u")
            vowel +=1
end

    i +=1

return vowel

end

puts("count_vowels(\"abcd\") == 1: #{count_vowels("abcd") == 1}")
puts("count_vowels(\"color\") == 2: #{count_vowels("color") == 2}")
puts("count_vowels(\"colour\") == 3: #{count_vowels("colour") == 3}")
puts("count_vowels(\"cecilia\") == 4: #{count_vowels("cecilia") == 4}")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to find vowels of a string using Ruby while loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769800/trying-to-find-vowels-of-a-string-using-ruby-while-loops)

Comment: Two ways: `"Now is the time to party!".scan(/[aeiou]/).size
=> 7` and `"Now is the time to party!".each_char.count { |c| c =~ /[aeiou]/ } #=> 7`.

Comment: yeah i know i can do that the exercise requires it this way.

Comment: You are missing `end` after `i += 1`.

Comment: It works fine if you add that missing end. In future, pay more attention to formatting your code, as you will see immediately if you are missing an `end`. Consider changing `if (string[i]=="a" || string[i]=="e"...); vowel +=1; end` to `case string[i]; when 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' then vowel += 1`; end`.

Answer (score 10):

```
def count_vowels(str)
  str.scan(/[aeoui]/).count
end
```

`/[aeoui]/` is a regular expression that basically means "Any of these characters: a, e, o, u, i". The [`String#scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-scan) method returns all matches of a regular expression in the string.

Comment: yeah i know i can do that the exercise requires it this way

Answer (score 6):

```
def count_vowels(str)
  str.count("aeoui")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is fine you are just missing a keyword `end` to close of your while loop

```
def count_vowels(string)
  vowel = 0
  i = 0

  while i < string.length
    if (string[i]=="a" || string[i]=="e" || string[i]=="i" || string[i]=="o"|| string[i]=="u")
      vowel +=1
    end
  i +=1
  end
  return vowel
end

puts("count_vowels(\"abcd\") == 1: #{count_vowels("abcd") == 1}")
puts("count_vowels(\"color\") == 2: #{count_vowels("color") == 2}")
puts("count_vowels(\"colour\") == 3: #{count_vowels("colour") == 3}")
puts("count_vowels(\"cecilia\") == 4: #{count_vowels("cecilia") == 4}")


#=> count_vowels("abcd") == 1: true
#=> count_vowels("color") == 2: true
#=> count_vowels("colour") == 3: true
#=> count_vowels("cecilia") == 4: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using HashTable data structure would be good way to go for this particular problem. Especially if you're required to output number of every single vowel separately.

Here is the code I'd use:

```
def vowels(string)

  found_vowels = Hash.new(0)

  string.split("").each do |char|
    case char.downcase
    when 'a'
      found_vowels['a']+=1
    when 'e'
      found_vowels['e']+=1
    when 'i'
      found_vowels['i']+=1
    when 'o'
      found_vowels['o']+=1
    when 'u'
      found_vowels['u']+=1
    end
  end

  found_vowels
end

p vowels("aeiou")
```

Or even this (elegant but not necessarily performant):

```
def elegant_vowels(string)

  found_vowels = Hash.new(0)

  string.split("").each do |char|
    case char.downcase
    when ->(n) { ['a','e','i','o','u'].include?(n) }
      found_vowels[char]+=1
    end
  end

  found_vowels
end

p elegant_vowels("aeiou")
```

which would output:

> {"a"=>1, "e"=>1, "i"=>1, "o"=>1, "u"=>1}

Answer (score 0):

So you don't have to turn the string into an array and worry about case sensitivity:

```
def getVowelCount(string)
  string.downcase.count 'aeiou'
end
```