# What is wrong with my Ruby vowel-counting loop?

Tags: ruby, string, loops

I'm trying to create a loop that add 1 to the *idx* every time theres a vowel in the string, but my code returns nothing.

```
def count_vowels(string)
  vowlcounter = 0 
  idx = 0 
  words = string.split('')

  while idx < string.length 
    if words[idx] == 'a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u'
      vowlcounter += 1 
      idx += 1
    end
  end

  return vowlcounter
end
```

Comment: What happens in your loop when i = 1? (Hint: nothing.)

Comment: In addition, `words[idx] == 'a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u'` is *not* how you test multiple values for equality. `a == b || c` evaluates as `(a == b) || c`, and if `c` is truthy, the entire expression is truthy. Your `if` will never be false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I count vowels?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26812757/how-do-i-count-vowels)

Comment: I admit I was looking for a canonical analogous to what @meagar was proposing, but considering that this particular problem has already been addressed in Ruby, it's fine.  If someone *does* find a canonical, that'd be good to know about.

Comment: @meagar the three things you summon to close are all in the question, it's crystal clear what he wants and what the problem is and the code is all there

Comment: @peter Absolutely nothing has been done to debug this. The code sample is *not* an MCVE, it contains all kinds of code unrelated to the actual problem at hand.

Comment: @meagar I disagree and I see others do also

Comment: You can disagree all you like, but it's objective truth that this is *not* the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: and you put it on hold based on that, no surprise you scary new users away

Comment: @peter OP has their answer, closing a question is not some "hostile" act. If the OP had gone through the simple exercise of producing the shortest code, they would have found their problem when they reached `while true; end`.  This question is not useful in its current form, and there is absolutely no reason to leave it open.

Comment: This code is on par for a very new Rubyist, and isn't a wall of code. It may be an X/Y problem, where X may have existing solutions, but the Y question lacks an exact duplicate. I think we all agree it could be debugged better, but it's not a terrible question, so I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @CodeGnome If you want to modify the question so that it's useful for other people, I'll happily reopen it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Regular expressions for shorter comparison if the string or char is a vowel. The other way like you wanted to would be way too long:

```
if words[idx] == 'a' || words[idx] == 'e'
```

And so on ...

Also if you would just increment `idx` everytime you have actually a vowel, you would get stuck in an infinite loop if the char isnt a vowel, `idx` would not increase, thus always checking for the same value in the while loop.

This code works by using Regular expression:

```
def count_vowels(string)
  vowlcounter = 0 
  idx = 0

  while idx < string.length
    if string[idx][/[aeiou]/]
      vowlcounter += 1;
    end
    idx += 1;
  end
  return vowlcounter
end
```

Comment: Why the downvote on this? The infinite loop is a clear issue in the original code that this sample addresses.

Comment: @quantumpotato:  It feels like this code is a lot longer than it needs to be, especially in the wake of a simple `count` method on String.

Comment: I wanted the OP to understand what I suggested. That's why I didnt change it that much. He also did not asked for any optimization in speed or in writing, I just gave him a tip.

Answer (score 2):

### Scan and Count Vowels

This strikes me as an [X/Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Rather than debugging your code, it may be better to simply use built-in String methods to count your vowels, rather than doing your own iteration through the string. Other people can address the Y in your X/Y problem, but I'd rather help you solve for X directly.

#### Using String#scan

Use [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/String.html#method-i-scan) and [Array#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html#method-i-count) to do this quickly and easily. While this doesn't account for `y` when used as a vowel, it should otherwise do what you want.

```
def vowel_count str 
  str.scan(/[aeiou]/).count
end

vowel_count 'foo'
#=> 2

vowel_count 'foo bar baz'
#=> 4
```

#### Using String#count

I like using #scan best, because it returns an array you can use elsewhere if you like and helps with debugging. However, if you don't care about *which* vowels are found, you can use the [String#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/String.html#method-i-count) method directly. For example:

```
def vowel_count str
  str.count 'aeiou'
end

vowel_count 'foo'
#=> 2

vowel_count 'foo bar baz'
#=> 4
```

The results are the same, but you loose the ability to introspect the values returned inside your method. YMMV.

Comment: This does absolutely nothing to address the actual problem being described in the question.

Comment: @meagar It's an X/Y problem. If you want to answer the Y problem, go ahead, but I'd rather solve for X. YMMV.